# Create host-specific facts with an ansible custom module

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I'm writing an ansible custom module that does the same as the URI module with some additional features. 
In particular, I would like the data returned to be available either as a global var or as host specific var 
(where the host is the inventory host running the task).
based on a value passed to the module.

However, no matter what I do it seems that I can only create a global variable.
Let's say that I run the playbook for N hosts and I execute the custom module only once (run_once: yes).

```
[...]
   - name: Run the custom module and generate output in custom_var
     run_once: yes
     custom_module:
       field1: ...
       field2: ...
       global_data: yes -> yes, to create a global fact called: custom_var

   - name: DEBUG - Print the content of custom_var
     debug: msg="{{ custom_var }}"
```

This works fine, all N hosts are able to see the custom_var.
Is there a way that I can have custom_var defined only for the actual host that executes the task?

Strangely enough, I also tried to register the result of the first task as follows:

```
[...]
   - name: Run the custom module and generate output in custom_var
     run_once: yes
     custom_module:
       field1: ...
       field2: ...
       global_data: no -> no, if I don't create any global fact
     register: register_task

   - name: DEBUG - Print the content of custom_var
     debug: msg="{{ register_task }}"
```

but it looks like that also was available to all the hosts in the inventory (with the same content). Is that the expected behaviour?
And any idea about how to make the custom_var available only for the host that actually runs the task?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't see any code in your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is expected behaviour with `run_once: yes` as it overrides host loop.

With this option set, the task is executed only once (on the first host in a batch) but result is copied to all hosts in the same batch. So you end up with `custom_var`/`register_task` defined for every host.

If you want the opposite, you can change `run_once: yes` to conditional statement like:

```
    when: play_hosts.index(inventory_hostname) == 0
```

This will execute the task only on the first host but will not override host loop (still skip the task for other hosts because of conditional); This way registered fact will be available only for the first host.

Comment: Hi Konstantin,

Thanks I was not aware of that! I thought I was creating a global fact from the module but it was actually the use of run_once to make it globally available.